# Get notification when a user wants to add data to the database

Tags: android, database, back4app

I'm about to begin working on a recipe Android app for my college final project, and I want users to be able to add recipes to the database. However, I don't want the data to be added right away, but I'd like to receive a notification whenever someone wants to add a recipe, so I can confirm it myself. I'm using back{4}app by the way.

How can I do such a thing in a not-so-complicated way? I was thinking to create an admin account for myself in the app itself, but is there any way to send the notifications to said account? I also want to be able to confirm recipe addition with a simple "Confirm" button from within the app, so will this require me to create an additional class for pending recipes? Will I need an admin account in any case?

Comment: I don't know what back4app is, but would it satisfy your assignment to simply upload the data as normal, but have an additional field, "approved" ... that you would manually set directly in the database yourself?  You could have an email sent to you when the users upload something.

Comment: Create  2 tables. 1 live recipes,  1 not live. when a user adds a recipe its goes in the not live. You could send yoursefl an email when a recipe has been added on the not live table. You then create yourself an admin area to view the not live recipe and approve it, or not. If you do approve then it will be a simple copy from the Not live to the Live table

Comment: To add to my previous comment, you could do it in 1 table. But you need to add a extra column eg (live) this takes in 0 or 1. When a user adds a recipe  you insert it in the table with a 0. If you approve you change to 1. The outside world will only see the rows that have a live = 1. For you admin area you code it to view what rows have a live = 0 and if you approve you change it (live) to 1

Comment: @BooberBunz It would satisfy my assignment, but it wouldn't satisfy me. If I was going to do it the way you suggested, how will I get a notification of recently added recipes?

Comment: @Tasos I like the idea of the extra live column, seems much more efficient than creating an additional table (called "class" in back{4}app, which is based on Parse.com). Then if I don't approve it it would simply get removed from the database. How do I create the admin area though?

Comment: @Tasos u stole my idea!! Jk. user350... you would bd notified by email just as i said and Tasos repeated.

Comment: The Admin area should be web based as a portal where you can log in and perform all the functions you need. If you use PHP then usercake or UserPie would be fine

Comment: @Tasos It seems that User Cake requires SQL server, and back{4}app is a NoSQL server. Aren't there any alternatives? Plus, I have no idea whatsoever how to work with PHP.

Comment: @BooberBunz I'm thinking if I'm going to make it so I get notified by email, maybe I could make it send the ID of the recipe that was added so I can approve it from within the app. Or should I just manually change the "approved" column on the database itself? Can't I just create an activity in the app that's available only to me?

Comment: Yes it would be better to make a separate activity OR create different levels of users (like windows: user, admin), and have recipoes only visible to you (or other members of your group) until you approve them... i was just saying if you were pressed for time the email/manual method would be faster.

Comment: @BooberBunz So you mean for example create an "admin level" and make the activity available only to them? Or make just certain options available only to admins? How can I implement such a thing? Can you direct me somehow, like what should I search in Google for example? Or maybe if there's a link or something... Thanks a lot.

Comment: Since you havent started building your app yet, I would strongly suggest Google Firebase.  I built an entire app with PHP / mySQL only to find out how much easier it was with Firebase.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yt75ZIGdJ4Y  ... that video is an overview... for more specific subjects there is an entire youtube channel for it.

Comment: @BooberBunz The server I'll be working with, back{4}app, is a NoSQL server and works with JSON in a similar way to Firebase, but you see the data in tables, which I found much more convenient. I tried Firebase but since I'm used to tables, I wasn't very comfortable with it. Maybe I'll give it another chance if you think it's easier. What about my previous questions though? Can you direct me somehow as to how can I implement what I mentioned?

Comment: Sorry I'm still learning myself, I can't help you design your app it sounds quite complex... maybe post a new question now that you've narrowed down what you want to do more?

Answer (score 1):

all this can be achieve by using cloud code.

```
Parse.cloud.define("addRecipe", function(request, response) {
    const query = new Parse.Query("recipe");
    query.set("name", "name");
    query.save({
         success function(result) {
              response(result);
              //call push notification function from client or from cloud code when the error is nil 
         },
         error: function(result, error) {
          response(error);
          }
    });
});
```

this is an example of push notifications using cloud code.
push notification are not allow anymore from the client due to secure reason.
you should be subscribe to this channel

```
Parse.Cloud.define("pushsample", function (request, response) {
    Parse.Push.send({
        channels: ["channelName"],
        data: {
            title: "Hello!",
            message: "Hello from the Cloud Code",
        }
   }, {
        success: function () {
            // Push was successful
            response.sucess("push sent");
        },
        error: function (error) {
        // Push was unsucessful
        response.sucess("error with push: " + error);
        },
        useMasterKey: true
   });
});
```

you should also implement some logic to your app in order to display recipes confirm by admin.

```
var recipe = Parse.Object.extend("recipe");
var query = new Parse.Query(recipe);
query.equalTo("confirm", true);
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    //it will display recipes confirmed
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  });
```

you should also setup a admin system in your app or a website